# Please recommend pretty Java Swing components library

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I am right now working on a job of  retouching the user interface of a software which is coded in Java. The interface is now built using Swing. I am looking for a library of Java Swing components, which should look better than the original `JComponent`s.

I have already found [SlickerBox](http://code.deckfour.org/slickerbox/); the components there look much better than the originals. However, I don't like the color of the components in SlickerBox, and I can't find the way to customize the color. I am looking for a better library.

I would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Why not use the standard java Look and Feels there are plenty:

- [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/products/swing-suite/)
- [JTatoo](http://www.jtattoo.net/)
- [Jide look and feel](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/)
- [Liquidlnf](http://java.net/projects/liquidlnf/)
- [Napkin LaF](http://napkinlaf.sourceforge.net/)
- [PgsLookAndFeel](http://www.pagosoft.com/projects/pgslookandfeel/)
- [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/index.html) (looks like aqua from MacOS X)
- [Seaglass](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/)
- [The Alloy Look and Feel](http://lookandfeel.incors.com/)
- The [native](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for your system
- The [nimbus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html) LaF
- The [substance](http://java.net/projects/substance/) project (forked into the [Insubstantial](https://github.com/Insubstantial) project)
- [WebLookAndFeel](http://weblookandfeel.com/)

Also see here for more free L&Fs:

- [javootoo.com](http://www.javootoo.com/)
- [Synthetica Themes - Custom L&Fs](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/themes/)

Alternatively you may want to know how to create your own:

- [How to Write a Custom Look and Feel](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html)

Or [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/) might be what you need

Java Look And Feel Libraries/Engines:

- [Cezanne L&F engine](http://www.centigrade.de/en/products/cezanne-look-and-feel-engine)

#### References :

- [Best Java Swing Look and Feel Themes | Top 10](http://www.taranfx.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10)
- [oracle.com - Modifying the Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)
- [wikipedia.org - Pluggable look and feel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel)
- [Java2s.com - Look and feel](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Look-And-Feel-LaF.htm)
- [Java Look and Feel (L&F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf)

Comment: +1 - phew, this is almost an exhaustive list (*if not completely exhaustive*), loved it! I'm going to save this for future reference ;)

Comment: an excellent collection. Cezanne looks awesome!

Comment: Great review. Well, although I have already make up my mind to use jGoodies though ;) Still, it's nice to compare it with other solution.

Comment: Which of them are okay on "Retina" displays? (not only on OS X, there are laptops on Win 8 with high DPI screens now, too)

Comment: This one is very sexy and modern looking https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend javaFX, it supports CSS. Sky's the limit plus you get a friendly UI builder by oracle check them out [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html)!