# How do I make sexy user interfaces in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swt

I am planning to develop a desktop application that allows to manage client data. I am an experienced Java programmer but I have never really been able to do attractive interfaces in Java, for instance, I personally think the default Swing components are horrible (when I compare it for example with a recent web interface).

So first question would be, how can I make sexy interfaces in Java (that still run on all platforms) ?
Secondly, wouldn't it be a good idea to make the interface in HTML5? Isn't it possible to run an HTML5 interface without a web server, as I don't need the application to be accessible online, thus I don't need a server.

Comment: See the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/).

Comment: You might want to search for Java's new Avatar project, too

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd couple an HTML5 interface to application logic without a server. It can probably be done, i just have no idea how. Note that a web server is not a difficult thing to add to an application; there is one [built into the JRE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html).

Comment: See this similar questions answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12322344/1133011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Metal Look and feel is not friendly (at all), and let's not even
  consider Motif.
- Nimbus does a much better job, but still does not look right nor feel
  natural
- However, on each platform, you can use the "System" look and feel:
  looks ok, feels natural-->Good user experience.
- If you want to create you own look and feel, take a look at Synth. It
  is a little bit like you could apply CSS to your Swing components.

To use the System look and feel, nothing easier than calling this (before starting any UI related things):

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Motif ... I have users who are actually using that and even worse, like it. Specially the extra clicks you have to do to access a submenu.

Answer (score 4):

The default Metal Look and Feel is not too attractive, I agree, but there are other Look and Feels for Java. Nimbus is included in the JRE since Java SE 6 Update 10, which is newer than Metal and looks cooler, you might wanna check that out:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

Also there are many external Look and Feels which you can download and bundle with your application. Some examples:

http://geeknizer.com/best-java-swing-look-and-feel-themes-professional-casual-top-10/

http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Look-And-Feel-LaF.htm

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of really nice APIs for that. One of the best was [Substance](https://github.com/kirillcool/substance), which is officially discontinued but there is an active fork called [Insubstantional](https://github.com/Insubstantial/insubstantial).

It's pretty easy and you can customize it heavily, [see more screenshots here](http://insubstantial.github.com/insubstantial/substance/see.html) like this:

[image]

You may find the [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) and the [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net/) projects also interesting.

You can also take a look on [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/), it is possible to include JavaFX components in Swing applications (you can find interesting articles about that in the [Java Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamagazine/index.html)) and vice versa. You would like it because you can use CSS for example to customize the outlook.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a traditional desktop app, you might like to look at [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), an alternative widget tookit. It's the widget set used for the Eclipse IDE; i think that looks pretty good, certainly much better than most Swing apps (cough cough IntelliJ).

Comment: Why doesn't anyone mention SWT except you?:)

Comment: @Matthew Because SWT is not native in JVM, so this means you need extra-libs and also because SWT is not compatible with Swing/AWT which means that it is hard to switch from to the other.

Comment: No, it is because i am the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

> I personally think the default Swing components are horrible (when I compare it for example with a recent web interface).

- yes (since 2001/2 stable GUI, with long buggy history, there is quite everything possible)
- not, most of web interface looks like as Circus

> So first question would be, how can I make sexy interfaces in Java (that still run on all platforms) ?

use [Custom Look and Feel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3954646/714968) for Swing GUI

> Secondly, wouldn't it be a good idea to make the interface in HTML5? Isn't it possible to run an HTML5 interface without a web server, as I don't need the application to be accessible online, thus I don't need a server.

this possible [official Oracle API for JavaFX2.x](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/fx/overview/index.html), [or ???](http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-use-javafx-2-instead)