# Customize Swing Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing

It seems like many people like to use swing, I have been looking at it to use in my project, but the issue that I face is that I don't like how it looks. I do like how Photoshop looks though, and was wondering: is it possible to make swing look a little bit like the below image? If you have any tutorials on this please post the links!

[image: PhotoShop Swing Menu]

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf

Comment: Adding on to @Guillaume comment (+1) see here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322296/please-recommend-pretty-java-swing-components-library/12322344#12322344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you really want to spend the time to make it look like that then you can use Synth to create our own skin over it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html
http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/synth/index.html