# JCheckBox in all nodes of a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, jcheckbox

I am trying to make:

- A JTree where ALL nodes have the possibility of a JCheckBox.
- After having selected the different checkboxes I would like to be able to extract strings stating the node path to the different checked nodes.
- The leader node must be able to show if a child node has been selected.

I have included a small SSCCE

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class ptf_viewer extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static JTree tree = new JTree();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ptf_viewer frame = new ptf_viewer();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
    public ptf_viewer() throws Exception
    {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(50);

        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_1;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_2;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_3;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_4;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_5;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_6;
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Aarhus");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("generator");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("photovoltaic"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("human");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("lossOfMains"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("residualCurrent"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("quality");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("harmonics       "));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("flicker"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("powerFactor"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcEmission"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("support");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("faultRideTrough"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reactivePower"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("fault");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortCircuit"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("all"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Billund");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("generator");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("photovoltaic"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("human");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("lossOfMains"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("residualCurrent"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("quality");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("harmonics       "));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("flicker"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("powerFactor"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcEmission"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("support");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("faultRideTrough"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reactivePower"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("fault");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortCircuit"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("all"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Christiansfeld");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("generator");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("photovoltaic"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("human");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("lossOfMains"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("residualCurrent"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("quality");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("harmonics       "));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("flicker"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("powerFactor"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcEmission"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("support");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("faultRideTrough"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reactivePower"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("fault");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortCircuit"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("all"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Daugaard");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("generator");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("photovoltaic"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("human");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("lossOfMains"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("residualCurrent"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("quality");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("harmonics       "));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("flicker"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("powerFactor"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcEmission"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("support");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("faultRideTrough"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reactivePower"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("fault");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortCircuit"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("all"));
                    add(node_1);
                    node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Esbjerg");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("generator");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("photovoltaic"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("human");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("lossOfMains"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("residualCurrent"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("quality");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("harmonics       "));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("flicker"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("powerFactor"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcEmission"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("support");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage");
                                node_3.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("faultRideTrough"));
                            node_2.add(node_3);
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reactivePower"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("fault");
                            node_2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortCircuit"));
                        node_1.add(node_2);
                        node_1.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("all"));
                    add(node_1);
                }
            }
        ));
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        tree.setBounds(174, 32, 301, 420);
        getContentPane().add(tree);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code

[image]

.

.

with JCheckBox (uncoment)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.tree.*;


public class CheckBoxNodeTreeSample {

    public CheckBoxNodeTreeSample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Tree");
        //setLookAndFeel();
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(50);

        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        tree.setModel(new DefaultTreeModel(
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("test") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                {
                  DefaultMutableTreeNode node_1;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_2;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_3;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_4;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_5;
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node_6;
                   node_1 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Aarhus");
                        node_2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("protection");
                            node_3 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("grid");
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("plant");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
                                node_4 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("unit");
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("disconnection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("LOM"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("dcImmunity"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("stability");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("current"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("connection");
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                        node_5.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                    node_4.add(node_5);
                                    node_5 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("reconnection");
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("longInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                        node_6 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("shortInterrupt");
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("voltage"));
                                            node_6.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("frequency"));
                                        node_5.add(node_6);
                                   node_4.add(node_5);
                                node_3.add(node_4);
 //removed overloaded limit 30k chars 
                         }
        }
    ));

        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
// original code      
        /*CheckBoxNode accessibilityOptions[] = {new CheckBoxNode(
            "Move system caret with focus/selection changes", false),
            new CheckBoxNode("Always expand alt text for images", true)};
        CheckBoxNode browsingOptions[] = {
            new CheckBoxNode("Notify when downloads complete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Disable script debugging", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Use AutoComplete", true),
            new CheckBoxNode("Browse in a new process", false)};
        Vector<Object> accessVector = new NamedVector("Accessibility", accessibilityOptions);
        Vector<Object> browseVector = new NamedVector("Browsing", browsingOptions);
        Object rootNodes[] = {accessVector, browseVector};
        Vector<Object> rootVector = new NamedVector("Root", rootNodes);
        tree = new JTree(rootVector);
        CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
        tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
        tree.setCellEditor(new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree));
        tree.setEditable(true);*/
//        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CheckBoxNodeTreeSample();
            }
        });
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

    private JCheckBox leafRenderer = new JCheckBox();
    private DefaultTreeCellRenderer nonLeafRenderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
    private Color selectionBorderColor, selectionForeground, selectionBackground,
            textForeground, textBackground;

    protected JCheckBox getLeafRenderer() {
        return leafRenderer;
    }

    public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
        Font fontValue;
        fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
        if (fontValue != null) {
            leafRenderer.setFont(fontValue);
        }
        Boolean booleanValue = (Boolean) UIManager.get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
        leafRenderer.setFocusPainted((booleanValue != null) && (booleanValue.booleanValue()));
        selectionBorderColor = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBorderColor");
        selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
        selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
        textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
        textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

        Component returnValue;
        if (leaf) {
            String stringValue = tree.convertValueToText(value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, false);
            leafRenderer.setText(stringValue);
            leafRenderer.setSelected(false);
            leafRenderer.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());
            if (selected) {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(selectionForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(selectionBackground);
            } else {
                leafRenderer.setForeground(textForeground);
                leafRenderer.setBackground(textBackground);
            }
            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                Object userObject = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
                if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode) {
                    CheckBoxNode node = (CheckBoxNode) userObject;
                    leafRenderer.setText(node.getText());
                    leafRenderer.setSelected(node.isSelected());
                }
            }
            returnValue = leafRenderer;
        } else {
            returnValue = nonLeafRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,
                    value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
    private ChangeEvent changeEvent1 = null;
    private JTree tree;

    public CheckBoxNodeEditor(JTree tree) {
        this.tree = tree;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        JCheckBox checkbox = renderer.getLeafRenderer();
        CheckBoxNode checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNode(checkbox.getText(),
                checkbox.isSelected());
        return checkBoxNode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject event) {
        boolean returnValue = false;
        if (event instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(),
                    mouseEvent.getY());
            if (path != null) {
                Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
                if ((node != null) && (node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode)) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;
                    Object userObject = treeNode.getUserObject();
                    returnValue = ((treeNode.isLeaf()) && (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNode));
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
            boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row) {

        Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
        ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {// editor always selected / focused
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent) {
                if (stopCellEditing()) {
                    fireEditingStopped();
                }
            }
        };
        if (editor instanceof JCheckBox) {
            ((JCheckBox) editor).addItemListener(itemListener);
        }
        return editor;
    }
}

class CheckBoxNode {

    private String text;
    private boolean selected;

    public CheckBoxNode(String text, boolean selected) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean newValue) {
        selected = newValue;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String newValue) {
        text = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + "[" + text + "/" + selected + "]";
    }
}

class NamedVector extends Vector<Object> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public NamedVector(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NamedVector(String name, Object elements[]) {
        this.name = name;
        for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {
            add(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, unfortunately I can not load "import org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceOfficeSilver2007LookAndFeel;"

Comment: remove this code line has nothing to do with that, forgot to clean up import, btw this is one the best of  [Custom Look and Feel for Java6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf) everything looks like as miracles

Comment: hmm I got the example to compile however I am not getting the desired result, judt getting a blank jframe