# java L&F to obtain modern "wpf" look

Tags: java, wpf, swing, look-and-feel

Recently I found some absolutely beautiful applications made using WPF. 
I'd really like to add this lovely look to my java applications.

[image]

Do you know if there are look and feels which make it possible?

Comment: Feel free to put one toegther !

Answer (score 4):

First of all think what are the key concepts of the new metro-UI ? 
Its flat and simple

1) use metro studio 2 to create icons for the project, use flat borders always

2) either create a full L&F or simply create small custom components ? or use Java FX (http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/jmetro-windows-8-controls-on-java/ , http://pixelduke.wordpress.com/category/javafx/page/3/)

I was able to come little bit close to metro like text-buttons and background repeat panels, you might also want to see my repo here https://github.com/JaDogg/BhathiGUI

[image: Bhathi GUI]

above image is for my near metro custom controls

NOTE : this will not create an actual metro app just one that looks like it

---

## Update

Here is a screenshot of JavaFX application built using [Undecorator](https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator) and JMetro (JavaFX8)
[image: JavaFX]

Comment: I recommend JavaFX and Java 8. With controlfx or fxextras.

Answer (score 1):

Java was always stingy on new L&F. So new WPF style (developed for Windows 8 apps) is not available yet and i doubt it will be anytime soon.

The latest L&F released and provided together with Java SE was NimbusLookAndFeel. It is based on SynthLookAndFeel, which supposed to be a base for any custom L&F from now on.

There are also native L&Fs with:

- Windows 2000 and Vista/7 styles (WindowsLookAndFeel)
- GTK style (GTKLookAndFeel)
- Mac OS style (AquaLookAndFeel)

There are also some good commercial L&Fs: 
[Java Look and Feel (L&F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf)

So if you really want to have such L&F - you will have to modify some existing L&F so it matches WPF styling or wait for a miracle (that someone will release such L&F).