# How I can apply different themes to a desktop swing softwares?

Tags: java, swing, themes

I want to apply different themes to the components like jframes, panels, components. I would like to create a theme for working with data from files (XML, JSON or the same).

Comment: Check out [Synth L&F](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html)

Comment: thanks. I will read.

Comment: And what is your question? Telling you about external tools/libraries would be off-topic. Asking how to do it in general a DUP to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf ... so most likely, your question should be put on hold/closed ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, you need to consider a different theme like webapp, desktop GUI using swing components or midi app. It will be related with more criteria.

There are some links for L&F:

```
  String srt1 = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel";
  String srt2 = "javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel";
  String srt3 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel";
  String srt4 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel";
  String srt5 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel";
  String srt6 = "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel";
...
```

EXAMPLE of USING (for example in constructor):

```
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(srt1);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Comment: where this parameter `str1` comes from ?

Comment: "str1" is a string variable of the sources. Also, you can find it easy, for example here: http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Swing/Look-And-Feel-LaF.htm