# Alternative to JCheckboxMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As I'm (re)building a GUI in Java, I see some things in Java Swing are not so pretty, or the options are not as rich as in some other GUI frameworks. 
So in the old GUI, this is what we see
[image: The "ondertekenen" is a toggle with an icon]

Now when I try to remake this with Swing, this is my best guess:

[image: Unselected toggle]
[image: Selected toggle]

My question: is there a more elegant and neat way to make a toggle work in a menu, while also using an icon in Swift? I don't want a checkbox and an icon, I want an icon instead of a checkbox, at the place of the checkbox. As can be seen in the old GUI picture.

Comment: If I had to guess, you should first try and change the look and feel to the system look and feel, your old GUI is either a Windows application, or uses Windows-"look and feel". The 'default' platform-independent look and feel is rather ugly in some respects. See also [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/java-look-and-feel-lf

Comment: Ah thanks! I knew there should be a way to change the whole looks of the GUI, now I know how, needed the right term